# Should the mass of the electron be included in the mass of products when calculating mass defect?

Tags: electrons, nuclear-physics

In a physics question, I encountered a beta minus decay reaction. If I were to calculate the mass defect, should the mass of the electron be included in the mass of the products?

Comment: Yes, it should.

Comment: Yes.............

Comment: Thank you so much!